# How to get token for HTTP request if I am using NextAuth

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have created a session with next 13.4.19 and nextAuth 4.23.1, also have a  middleware to protect routes, it works fine, when I log an user I get a session and the session token, (next-auth.session-token), but I need to send more http request with the user token , not with the session token, the question is how could I get that token.

I have the login http request in NextAuth configuration and it return user info and his token too, but how could I get that user token in a middleware to send more HTTP requests?

This is my first Next app, I hope you could explain me how to to do this.

**In /src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts**

Here I configure the credential provider and the user by http request (this is the token I need to use for other http request)

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { _AUTH } from "@/app/services/shared/endpoints";

export const handler = NextAuth({
  session: { strategy: "jwt" },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const res = await fetch(_AUTH._AUTH_LOGIN, {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify({ user: { ...credentials } }),
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        });
        if (res.status === 200) {
          const user = await res.json();
          //console.log("HERE  THE USER TOKEN I NEED TO GET IN A MIDDLEWARE ================>",user.token)
          if (!user) {
            return;
          } else {
            return user;
          }
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
  callbacks: {
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      return `/empresa/mis-empresas`     
    }
  }
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

**in middleware.ts**

Here I get the session token, to protect my routes, I want to create a middleware here to add headers and send user token for every http request.

```
export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {

  const session = req.cookies.get("next-auth.session-token")
  if(session === undefined){
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/`, req.url));
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/empresa/mis-empresas',
  ]
}
```